# jQuery Ajax call performed multiple times - Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I am running into a situation in Chrome where a single Ajax call is being performed multiple times (20 times to be exact).

I have an input field that gets triggered when you enter in 5 digits into the zip field.

I am trying to perform a zip code / state validation in my ajax call.

I am crossing domains.

The code performs correctly in Firefox. It makes the single call, and performs the proper maintenance.(see code).  The maintenance is nothing significant. It's assigns a title value or changes a class. Nothing that should cause my ajax call to perform multiple times.

I have checked my code.  It is not being called 20 times.

I have put counters in my code to see if the function is being called multiple times and it's only being done once.

The reason for the onKeyUp and onInput was to handle if someone typed into the field, or double-clicked on it and used a cached value.

So in Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113, the Ajax call is performed 20 times, and on the 21st, it cancels itself.

I am also using jQuery instead of $ because there is other code being used that I don't have any control over.

Any and all help would be appreciated.  If I am missing something, please let me know.

Here's the input field code:

```
<input id="zipPostal" name="zipPostal" type="text" placeholder="Postal Code" onkeyup="zipValid1()" oninput="zipValid1()"  />
```

Here's the jquery code:

```
        function zipValid1(){

        var x = jQuery("#zipPostal").val();
        if (x != '00000' && x.length == 5){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'https://myurl/getzip.cfm',
                type:'POST',
                crossDomain:true,
                data: {zipcode: x},
                success: function(data){
                    if (data.trim() == 'Invalid'){
                     (perform CSS and JS maintenance)
                    }                       
                    else{
                     (perform CSS and JS maintenance)
                    }
                } // closes Success
            }); // ajax
        }
        else{
           (perform CSS and JS maintenance)
        }
    };
```

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried rebinding the keypresses with `$(document).unbind('keypress').bind('keypress', function (e) { });`? See [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987454/input-fires-keypress-event-twice) and also [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387316/jquery-textbox-keyup-firing-twice).

Answer (score 0):

Your function `zipValid1` gets called on every keyup and input, which when typing it is called twice for each character you type into the input.

A standard approach to fix this issue is to "debounce" the function called until after the user has stopped typing.

This is a popular jQuery library to help with this issue. http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Here is a simple example of debouncing the function and waiting until 500ms after the user has stopped typing.

```
var timeout;

function zipValid1() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    var x = jQuery("#zipPostal").val();
    if (x != '00000' && x.length == 5) {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://myurl/getzip.cfm',
        type: 'POST',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: {
          zipcode: x
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.trim() == 'Invalid') {
              // (perform CSS and JS maintenance)
            } else {
              // (perform CSS and JS maintenance)
            }
          } // closes Success
      }); // ajax
    } else {
      // (perform CSS and JS maintenance)
    }
  }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Hi Itodd - Thanks for the suggestion on modifying it. I'm not worried about it running a lot, simply because the person just needs to type in a 5 digit zip code, and the function only runs once 5 digits are entered.

The weight of another JS script vs. having a function be hit 5 times and only performing once is negligible.  But I will keep your debounce script suggestion in my tool box. 

Any ideas on what would cause Chrome to run the ajax portion 20 times?