# auto search keyup firing twice

Tags: jquery, keyup

I am using keyup event for autosearch from text field. But it triggers twice. If I bind method use it called once but in some pages it called twice.

```
$('#tc-header-sticky-search-input').on("keyup input", function(e){});

$(document).on('keyup ','#tc-header-sticky-search-input', function(e){});
```

I used both above . But no success

Comment: Please include your html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387316/jquery-textbox-keyup-firing-twice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: textbox keyup firing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387316/jquery-textbox-keyup-firing-twice)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#contact-search-input').keyup(function () {
  console.log(this.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="contact-search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search Data">
```